# SuiteAnalytics Workbook to CSV

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suiteql

I’m trying to generate a CSV of a dataset via scripting. I’m using the task.create function and was able to generate a CSV File. the only problem is that I’m getting internalids instead of texts (example: 1234 is being returned instead of ItemName). I tried modifying the Query object’s column context name from RAW to DISPLAY but I’m still getting the same results.

Any advise on how to resolve this? thank you

Comment: please include example attempts simplified to a general case that helps others

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two options.

1. There is a builtin function that you can use in your query that behaves like `getText` does for saved searches.  That built-in function is `BUILTIN.DF` [docref](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/article_161950565221.html)

This function

> Returns the display value of a field from the target record type without having to join the target record type explicitly

This works for the name So your query can be:

```sql
select 
   SO.Entity as entity_id,
   BUILTIN.DF( SO.Entity ) as entity_name

  from 

    TRANSACTION SO /* no join to the entity needed here */
...
```

2. You could do the join

```sql
select 

SO.id,

/* next two are the same value */
SO.entity as entity_id,
Customer.id as customer_id,

/* next two are the same value */
BUILTIN.DF(SO.entity) as entity_name,
 Customer.companyname as customer_name

from 
Transaction SO
join Customer on SO.entity = Customer.id
```